# FVWM - Split Desktop into Multiple Virtual Desktops

Tags: linux, vmware, kde, xorg, window-manager

I have a Linux virtual machine running within VMware Fusion 3.

I have a dual monitor setup that runs thanks to the "vmware-user" application which enables both monitors as a single large display.

So, the physical layout of my monitors looks like so:

```
 ____________
|            |
|            |
|____________|
   ________
  |        |
  |        |
  |________|
```

And the VMware-tools application creates a large virtual screen that will contain the two physical screens.

```
 ____________         ____________ 
|            |       |            |
|            |       |            |
|____________|       |            |
   ________     ==>  |            |
  |        |         |            |
  |        |         |            |
  |________|         |____________|
```

I would like to somehow split my one large desktop into two "Virtual Desktops"...

```
 ____________         ____________         ____________
|            |       |            |       |            |
|            |       |            |       |            |
|____________|       |            |       |            |
   ________     ==>  |            |  ==>  |____________|
  |        |         |            |       |            |
  |        |         |            |       |            |
  |________|         |____________|       |____________|
```

My requirements are that I:

- Can still use FVWM instead of something else like KDE or GNOME
- Don't have to load an alternate video driver (I have no choice but to use the VMware video driver)

I have looked into some other articles where people mentioned using "fake xinerama" to achieve this, but I couldn't find any working links or documentation.

Thank you!

Additionally, two similar questions of mine that relate to this can be found at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032846/vmware-fusion-3-dual-monitors-in-linux-non-ubuntu/10340828#10340828 
[Xorg - FVWM - Dual Monitors connected to same display independently](https://superuser.com/questions/363380/xorg-fvwm-dual-monitors-connected-to-same-display-independently/417349#417349)

Comment: Please run `xrandr` and paste the output here. X has its own definition for "screen". My guess is that your current setup has only one "screen" with two "crtcs" attached. You probably want to have two "screens". You'll have to read the documentation... Read this: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/randrproto/tree/randrproto.txt

Comment: This question reminded me of http://ask.slashdot.org/story/10/01/28/206240/2-displays-and-2-workspaces-with-linux-and-x which I had recently looked at. Not that it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more of the documentation, it seems that I am effectively attempting to split a single "screen" into two screens. While this might be possible with RandR and the "fakeXinerama" patch, it means I have to have two separate instances of FVWM open, and I will have to use the mouse to change the focus each time I want to use CTRL+ to change the current virtual desktop for the current "screen".

All-in-all, it would seem that I would have to develop this feature myself, at least how I see it so far. Thank you to those who took the time to look over this question.